# Issue flagging a "difference" between 2 data fields using an IIf statement in Access query when one value is Blank/Null

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables with "like" fields and am simply trying to "flag" all records where the "like" fields are different.  For example, I have a description field in table #1 and a description field in table #2.

I created a new field titled `Description_Diff` with the formula `Descr_diff`: `IIf([Tbl 1 items].[description]<>[Tbl 2 items].[description],"diff","")`.

The issue I am having is that if one of the two values is Null/Blank it does not return a "diff".  I apologize in advance if this answer had already been covered, but upon searching the site was unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with *Nz*:

```
Descr_diff: IIf(Nz([Tbl 1 items].[description])<>Nz([Tbl 2 items].[description]),"diff",Null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you can't compare Null using any logical operator.

So `If 1 <> Null` doesn't work as a comparison.

Have a read here http://allenbrowne.com/casu-11.html and http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score -1):

use coalesce 
usage:

```
coalesce(value, defaultValue)
```

when comparing if it's null, throw in "" or -1 as a default value, then comparing with blank or default would return false

Use the coalesce in your query in the select

```
Select coalesce(id,-1), coalesce(firstname,"") From myTable
```

Comment: `coalesce` is not of Access.